# Makefile Compiler Options

Tags: makefile

I was trying to write a Makefile and working off examples. I found this code:

```
CC=gcc
DFLAG=
FLAGS=-g -Wall

all:prg

prg:prg.c lib.o
    $(CC) $(DFLAG) $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@
%.o:%.c %.h
    $(CC) $(DFLAG) $(FLAGS) -c $<
clean:
    rm -rf prg *.o
```

I have two questions. 
1) I know that `DFLAGS` is just a variable name but what would it be used for? 
2. What are "`$^ -o $@`" and "`$<`"?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: Did you read [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) documentation? It is explained. Also, try `make -p`. And the above makefile is not very conventional or nice.

Comment: Is there a specific section in the link you could point me to?

Answer (score 1):

`DFLAGS` is for "**D** ebug **FLAGS**". You would set it to `-g`, for example, to add debugging symbols that `gdb` can use.

`$^` expands to a space delimited list of dependencies for the current rule. See [here](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/1.19/makepp_variables.html#dependencies)

`$<` expands to the fist dependency of the rule. See [here](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/1.19/makepp_variables.html#dependencies)

`$@` expands to the target of the current rule. See [here](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/1.19/makepp_variables.html#target)

See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) and [this page](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/larger/makefiles.html) for more information.